# How can I configure Tomcat7 to use Jquery?

Tags: jquery, eclipse, tomcat, primefaces

I'm developing a web application with `Tomcat 7` and `JSF` with `Primefaces` components. I have some troubles because the local server doesn't execute any ajax event, neither the simplest one.

I want to know if there is some configuration to be done to use `JQuery`, that is needed by `Primefaces`, on `Tomcat`. Do I have also to include `JQuery` libraries on my Eclipse project?

Comment: You don't need to *configure Tomcat7 to use Jquery* there is no such thing...

And primefaces already come with jquery bundled inside...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Tomcat` has nothing to do with the `JQuery`. If you are already using `PrimeFaces` it has `JQuery` by it self, you just need to import it properly into your head section of `XHTML` page. For e.g. I am using `JQuery` from `PrimeFaces` and I have constructed the following `XHTML` head:

```
<h:head xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="EmulateIE8"/>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
    <title>
        <h:outputText value="#{msg['application.name']}"/>
    </title>
    <f:view locale="en"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/css/style.css"/>
    <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js"/>
</h:head>
```

This:

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js"/>
```

line will import the `JQuery` from `PrimeFaces` and you will be able to use it in your project. Don't forget to remove all other `JQuery` libraries from you project and use only one which comes from `PrimeFaces`.